# C: Unexpected result when cast'ing an array within sizeof()

Tags: c, sizeof

I had to experience a(nother) - to me - unexpected C behavior, this time with `sizeof`.

My goal is trying to understand the reasoning behind this behavior and how I'd supposed to solve this. I'm not really interested in alternative solutions as my main goal is understanding what's happening here and why.

I'm having a string defined via the `#define`-C-preprocessor macro (`#define CONST "foobar"`) and use it in functions like:

`senddata(uint8_t * data, uint32_t len)`.

Since - depending on implementation/architecture, but at least on x86 - char is signed by default, I'm getting a warning about "differ[ence] in signedness" when calling it this way:

`senddata(CONST, sizeof(CONST))`.

So I'd have to cast it (`senddata((uint8_t *)CONST, sizeof(CONST))`) on every `senddata`-invocation.

Since all uses of CONST in my code were actually going to be cast'ed to `uint8_t` anyway, I figured I will just change the define:

`#define CONST "foobar"` -> `#define CONST ((uint8_t *)"foobar")`

and don't have to bother with further casting anymore.

While this indeed removes the warning and everything seems fine, I had to learn the hard way that in those cases sizeof() doesn't actually return the length of the string anymore, but the size of the data type, in this case `uint8_t *`.

To me this doesn't seem obvious at all.

So my question is 2 folded:

- 1) How would I do it right in above scenario?
- 2) Why is it the way it is?
- 3) How would I have been able to know about this? This is not meant (passive-)aggressively, but rather: with what prior knowledge should I have been able to come to the conclusion that this does not work that way?

Some half-knowledge I picked up somewhere which might play into this but I'm not quite sure what to make out of it: sizeof() is not a normal function but a operator (e.g. `sizeof int` works without brackets).

Another speculation of mine: `"foobar"` is a char-array while `(char *)"foobar"` is a pointer.

Comment: [POSIX `send()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/send.html) takes a `void*`

Comment: @pmg and 4 args, for that matter. daten - show us the actual snippet.

Comment: I'm sorry this caused confusion. `send` was just supposed to be a custom function name. I edited and changed it to `senddata`. Thanks for the pointer.

Comment: `senddata(uint8_t data, uint32_t len)` is probably a typo, it should be `senddata(uint8_t * data, uint32_t len)`, right? While you're at it, it would make more sense to change it to `senddata(const char *data, size_t len)`, because `char*` is the only pointer type which can alias structs.

Comment: Oh boy, yes, thanks. Was correct in the "So I'd have to cast it"-sentence though. Not sure I get the other comment about `const char *`. You mean in above post or in my code?

Comment: @daten: I meant in your code, since technically you shouldn't cast a struct pointer to anything other than `void*` or `char*`, where `char*` is the one which should be used to legally inspect the contents of a struct.

Comment: @SouravGhosh Thanks for the edits to my post btw, however I find it a bit odd, that you changed my BE writing to AE - was that on purpose?

Comment: @daten Not at all, my browser suggested that, and I had no intention to honor or dishonor either style. Frankly speaking, English is my fourth language, I learnt it after my university and I'm terrible at it.Apologies if the edit hurt in any way, it was completely unintentional.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are almost there, the thing you need to keep in mind that, `sizeof` works on the type of the operand, not the value.

Quoting `C11`, chapter §6.5.3.4

> The `sizeof` operator yields the size (in bytes) of its operand, which may be an
>   expression or the parenthesized name of a type. The size is determined from the type of
>   the operand. The result is an integer. If the type of the operand is a variable length array
>   type, the operand is evaluated; otherwise, the operand is not evaluated and the result is an
>   integer constant.

For example, `sizeof ("array")` is the same as `sizeof (char [6])`, because `"array"` is of type `char[6]`. Given that the size of a `char` is defined to be 1, it'll yield a result of 6.

However, when you use a cast for the operand of the `sizeof`, it considers that cast as the type as per the above definition. So, something like `sizeof ((char*)"array")` will be the same as `sizeof (char*)`. Based on your platform, it can yield a value of `4` or `8`, size of a pointer (to `char`).

Comment: This helps a lot, as it answers question (2) and (3). Anything on (1), even if it's "no"? Thank you!

Comment: @daten Well, the answer to (1) depends heavily on what you are actually trying to achieve with the `CONST` macro. I would generally try hard not to put a string literal into a preprocessor macro. It's just not the right tool for the purpose. If you must have a global name for it, put it into a global const variable/array, or return it as a singleton from a function.

Answer (score 0):

You're casting `CONST` - a string literal that acts as if it was an array `const char CONST[]` - to an **integer**. In such contexts, arrays degenerate to pointers, so you're basically **casting a pointer-to-string to an integer**. This is not what you want. Your `send` will not do anything sensible, unless your architecture has 8-bit-long pointers (that's 1-byte, not 8-bytes!).

What you really want is the following signature for send - notice that it is const correct as well:

```
void send(const void *, size_t);
```

And then you'd want a helper macro:

```
#define send_lit(literal) send(literal "", sizeof(literal))
```

This will fail if you try to invoke it with anything but a string literal, so it's relatively foolproof.

Complete example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#define send_lit(literal) send(literal "", sizeof(literal))

inline void send_byte(uint8_t byte) {
  // just an example implementation
  printf("%c", (char)byte);
}

void send(const void *src, size_t size) {
  const char *p = (const char *)src;
  while (size)
    send_byte((uint8_t)*p++);
}

int main() {
  send_lit("Hello, world!\n");
#if 0
  const char* p;
  send_lit(p); // won't compile
#endif
}
```